# To use "at" or [] to access member of std::vector safely

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I had an array

```
arr[10]
```

It tried to access

```
arr[12]
```

and program did not do anything until I realized when I switched to vectors. Somewhere I read that if I use `[]` then program would not give any runtime error again so that I should use `std::vector`'s `at`. But in my program I just used `[]` and it helped me to spot the problem. It seems `[]` is enough. Am I right? Also, is there any bound check for arrays for safety?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some implementations of the C++ library have a debug mode that will throw an exception even when you use the `[]` syntax, but this is not specified by the standard. So that may be what you experienced. If you want to be sure you should use `at()`.

C++ doesn't have bounds checking for primitive arrays, however if your compiler supports the newest version of C++ then you can use `std::array` instead of primitive arrays, and this container has an `at()` method just like `std::vector`.

I'd recommend using `std::array` even if you don't want this feature because primitive arrays have some other problems (e.g. they decay to pointers at the drop of a hat). `std::array` behaves much more consistently (e.g. you can pass them by value to functions or return them and they'll work correctly whereas writing the obvious syntax to pass an array by value will fail and will instead just pass a pointer).

Do yourself a favor and never use primitive arrays.

Comment: Does `at()` makes code slower because of some checks? Also, I cannot use `std::vector` because of lack of memory available. So, what is the size of `std::array` compared with raw array? One more thing, could `std::array` be used for dynamic allocation?

Comment: The extra bounds check would indeed slow things down a tad.  Not enough to justify not using it when you need it, of course.  :)  And if the compiler can figure out that the index will always be within the bounds of the container, a really smart optimizer could conceivably optimize that check away in some cases.  But if you already know that yourself, then `[]` is safe and `.at()` is overkill.

Comment: OK. What about the dynamic allocation for `std::array`. Here I don't mean I will change its size dynamically but its size will be determined at runtime only one time.

Comment: @Shibli: `std::array` doesn't use dynamic allocation; if you want that just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Shibil, the size of an `std::array` is always specified at compile time, just like a primitive array. `std::array <int,5> my_array`. See how the 5 is inside the `<>`, this makes it compile-time information. An `std::array` behaves *very* similarly to a primitive array in every way except that its a bit better and safer.

Comment: @Shibli `std::array` should have zero overhead as compared to raw arrays, however they can't be used for dynamically sized arrays because the size of the array is part of the type and must be determined at compile time. `std::vectors` work in this case and should have minimal overhead vs. an array, and you can set their size once when you create them and then not change it to avoid fragmenting memory and whatnot. The only downside of `std::vector` vs. a dynamically sized raw array is the few bytes of extra overhead, but that is a tiny price to pay for all the advantages `std::vector` offers.

Answer (score 3):

the `at()` function signals if the requested position is out of range by throwing an exception, and is therefore safer.